# From Bivariate to Multivariate Normal Distribution: An additive representation

Tags: multivariate-normal-distribution

Let's start with the bivariate case.

Let $X=Z_1$ and $Y=\rho Z_1 + \sqrt{1-\rho^2}Z_2$ where $Z_1$ and $Z_2$ follow two independent standard normal distribution, $\mathbb{N}(0,1)$. This means that
$\begin{pmatrix}
X \\
Y
\end{pmatrix}=\mathbb{N}\left(\begin{pmatrix}
0 \\
0
\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}
1 & \rho \\
\rho & 1
\end{pmatrix}\right)$

Say it differently, X and Y follow the standard normal distribution with correlation $\rho$.

Now, let's move the multivariate case. How can $Y$ be written if we suppose that $X=[X_1,\ldots,X_n]$ is now a vector of independent i.i.d standard normals:

$\begin{pmatrix}
X \\
Y
\end{pmatrix}=\mathbb{N}\left(\begin{pmatrix}
0 \\
\vdots \\
0
\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & \ldots & 0 & \rho_1 \\
0 & 1 & \ldots & 0 & \rho_2 \\
\vdots & 0 & \ldots & 0 & \vdots \\
0 & 0 & \ldots & 1 & \rho_{n} \\
\rho_1 & \rho_2 & \ldots & \rho_{n} & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix}\right)$

What is the formula?

Comment: The variance matrix in the two-variable case is not correctly presented.  If you would fix it, the parallels between that and the $n+1$-variable case should be so clear that the answer to your question ought to be apparent.

Comment: Sorry for the typo! But, I am still stuck...